# Angular container messes up the backend api

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I dockerized both applications, angular and spring boot application.
Spring boot app works fine and connects with the database container and everything is on point.
but when I try to send a request from front end, it generates a weird url, I don't know why.
this is the url it sends to.

> http://localhost:4200/http//localhost:8083/cloudit/api/v1

I've set up apiUrl in envirement.prod.ts, and used it in all my services.

here's the Dockerfile of springboot application.

```
FROM openjdk:21-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8083
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

here's the Dockerfile of angularApp

```
FROM alpine:3.13 as app
WORKDIR /app
COPY dist /app/dist

# Stage 2: Serve the Angular app using Nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine
COPY --from=app /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8081
ENV API_URL=http://localhost:8083
```

I ran npm install and build --prod locally.

and Here's docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mySQL:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : password
      MYSQL_DATABASE : db
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - net
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  app:
    image: cloudit
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mySQL
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_NAME: db
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - mySQL
    networks:
      - net
  front:
    image: frontend
    environment:
      API_URL: app:8083
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db:
```

I don't understand why is this [screenshot of error].
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHVL8.png)

Thank you in advance and if anyone got a way how to optimize or write a better Dockerfile, I'm open to any optimizations/suggestions.

Comment: "write a better Dockerfile" I'm surprised to see you copy a jar into the Dockerfile instead of copying the source and building within docker.  `http//localhost` I don't see it in your config, but that string exists somewhere in your code and is missing the`:` between `http` and `//`.  Thus it's not a full URL and your browser treats it as a relative path.   `API_URL: app:8083` this frontend runs in a browser, so you won't be connecting to `app:8083` it will actually be `localhost:8083` since your browser is not in docker.

Comment: @erik258 Thank you for taking the time and commenting on my issue, and thank you also for point that : , it completely slipped out of my mind, that : was missing in envirement.prod.ts, i fixed it, now they're communicating, now about copying the jar file only, just for testing purposes, and to gain a little bit of time, but i'm playing to do exactly like you said, about copying and building inside the container.
now i have another issue if you could help, cors origin is blocking communication to websocket even tho i have cors filter, so the other apis works fine, but websocket is blocked.